# Parsing stats file - Multiline pattern for Logstash (not error message)

Tags: pattern-matching, logstash, logstash-grok

My logfile has some stats like below coming from Kafka. How can I parse this values to put them into Influx DB. I'm new to Logstash. If not for the actual answer, tt would be great if someone could point me the material to learn doing this

```
[20200423 20:40:41.469 IST (StatsCollector-1) firm.pos.kafka.KafkaStatsCollector#logStats INFO] 

Kafka Statistics...
Total Time: 19743.848 s, Num of updates: 1322652, Updates/sec: 66.991, Transport time: 375599.683 ms/msg.


Topic wise number of updates published.
                    Topic              Updates/sec           Num of updates  Transport time (ms/msg)
 pos.user.1.2.agg                        0.000                        8               313370.000
pos.user.2.3.agg                         0.000                        1              1072398.000
 pos.user.4.53.agg                       0.002                       47               192315.383
pos.user.45.5.agg                        0.000                        2               626744.000
  pos.user.22.222.agg                    0.002                       49              1039206.755
  pos.user.222.44.agg                    0.000                        3                43196.000
 pos.user.242.42.seed                    0.000                        4               163960.750
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline pattern for logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552512/multiline-pattern-for-logstash)

Comment: I want to add the "Topic", "Updates/sec" as individual key in the resulting Json with the corresponding values. Basically I want to fetch the individual part and not just the whole text